# Getting wrong results in evaluating $\text{lim}_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(\pi \cos^2x)}{x^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

I have to evaluate the following limit: $$\text{lim}_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(\pi \cos^2x)}{x^2}$$

So I used this result: $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}=1$
Now I multiplied and divided this term: $(\pi \cos^2x)$.Hence:

$$\text{lim}_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(\pi \cos^2x)}{(\pi \cos^2x)}\cdot\frac{(\pi \cos^2x)}{x^2}$$
Treating $\sin(\pi \cos^2x)=\alpha$, We get:$$\text{lim}_{x\to 0}\frac{(\pi \cos^2x)}{x^2}\cdot 1$$

Now applying L'Hopital: $$\text{lim}_{x\to 0}(-\pi \cos x)\frac{\sin x}{x}=-\pi$$
But answer is $\pi$, and I couldn't find any mistake also. But I proceeded another way:

$$\text{lim}_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin[\pi-\pi \sin^2x]}{x^2}$$
$$\text{lim}_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(\pi \sin^2x)}{x^2}$$
And then in the same fashion, as done above, I got the correct answer $\pi$. I really can't figure out why the first method was wrong? So I need help there, as to why the first method leads to the wrong answer. Thanks in advance!

Comment: $\lim_{x\to0}\pi\cos^2x\ne0$

Answer (score 3):

In the first method you are assuming that $\frac  {\sin (\pi \cos^{2}x)} {\pi \cos^{2}x} \to 1$.  This is not correct because $\pi \cos^{2}x $ does not tend to $0$ as $x \to 0$.